# Trying to build GAE PHP runtime extension

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build GAE PHP runtime extension for local development.
I've followed instructions described in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension

When running the .configure i get the following error:

*configure: error: Invalid protobuf include path /home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension*

The configure command:

*./configure --enable-gae --with-protobuf_inc=/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension --with-protobuf_lib=/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension*

**/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension** is the absolut path to the headers and libraries created on the second step of the instructions:

> Set  and  to the absolute path to the protobuf headers and libraries installed in the previous step, usually /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib.

I've tryed to use /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib. Didn't work either. Does any one know what I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Typically libraries and include files are installed `include` and `lib` subdirectories.  Try appending those, as appropriate, to the paths passed to the options, and there's a reasonable chance it will work.

Comment: I've tryed that too. Didn't work.
After a long search, I discovered that the php app engine is for php5.5 only. So I gave up. Insted, I started to use Docker containers and a custom runtime env.
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Currently PHP 5.5 is supported for Google App Engine Standard, and PHP 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 (as stated by @George) are supported for App Engine Flexible as you can see in this link.https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/
If you have other requirements then yes you can build your own custom runtime following this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build

Answer (score 0):

Worthwhile mentioning in this context: for the Flexible Environment, it is now possible to run PHP 7.1, as detailed on the "PHP 7.1 for Google App Engine is generally available" [page](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/php-71-for-google-app-engine-is.html).

Regarding local development and testing, the Google Cloud SDK and App Engine SDK for PHP each include a local [development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server) that you can run locally to simulate your application running in production App Engine.